# PHP anomaly not working for num rows or others

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

```
<?php 






global $connect;

# Get the username from the email session
# 

$email = $_SESSION['username'];

$get_username = $connect->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
$get_username->bind_param("s", $email);
$get_username->execute();
$get_username->bind_result($username);
$get_username->fetch();
$get_username->close();

# End username



# Get user referrals 
# Gets how many users have in table "referral" the username of the user requesting the information 


$get_referrals = $connect->prepare("SELECT username,balance FROM users WHERE referral = ? ");
$get_referrals->bind_param("s", $username);
$get_referrals->execute();
$amount = $get_referrals->num_rows;
$get_referrals->close();


# End user referrals




# How many referrals user have

echo $amount; 

# End how many

?>
```

This query is not working, is always returning me 0 and was supposed to return 5  , can someone explain to me what is going on with this code.
The first query $username is returning me correct , only the second one is always returning me 0 and in sql tables I have atlas 5 referrals on this alias

Comment: check for errors, what do you get back? this via php and the queries

Comment: This issue is not verifiable without at least a dump of your SQL table structure.

Comment: there's also too much code missing

Comment: Where is [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) ?

Comment: Call `$get_referrals->store_result();` __right before__ `$amount = $get_referrals->num_rows;`

Comment: Name "Referral"  varchar(1000) latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 0):

`$get_referrals->num_rows` will return 0 unless you call `$get_referrals->store_result()` right after closing the statement. It returns zero because the result is still not stored in the memory. That's what `store_result` does, it stores the result in memory so that `num_rows` can return the number of returned rows